# Restrict the parameters in a minimization

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimization

For my information theory class, I have to maximize the next function:

```
def MutualInfo_Channel(P):
    sum_i = 0
    for i in range(len(P)):
        sum_j = 0
        for j in range(len(Q[i])):
            sum_t = 0
            for t in range(len(P)):
                sum_t += P[t]+Q[t][j]
            sum_j += Q[i][j]*math.log(Q[i][j]/sum_t, 2)
        sum_i += P[i]*sum_j
    return sum_i
```

where `P = [0.4, 0.5, 0.1]`. I've searched methods for doing this, and everything points to the `optimize.minimize` function included in SciPy. I've already coded the method but I need to apply the next restricions:

- All values in P must be between 0 and 1.
- The sum of all values in P
  must be equal to 1.
- P can have n values.

My current code looks this way:

```
P_In = [0.4, 0.5, 0.1]
Q = [[0.94, 0.04, 0.02], [0.01, 0.93, 0.06], [0.03, 0.04, 0.93]]

Cc = minimize(MutualInfo_Channel, P_In)
if Cc.success:
    optimal = Cc.x
    print(optimal)
else:
    raise ValueError(Cc.message)
```

Is it possible to add all the restrictions described above? How can I apply them to my minimize function?

Comment: First two are trivial; read the docs (especially the tutorial) in terms of variable-bounds (1) and constraints (2). But what do you mean by restriction (3)? Depending on the interpretation of this, it's not possible to do this in scipy (interpretation: discrete set of values to choose from).

Comment: Restriction (or rule) #3 means the array can have multiple values.

Comment: That's not precise. Try to formalize it? E.g. in every feasible solution, the number of unique elements in P is <=2. This for example won't work in scipy! Or are you just saying it's an vector of a-priori defined size N?